# An elementary proof that low rank maps cannot be open

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a smooth open map ($n \ge m$). Then it cannot happen that $\text{rank}(df)<m$ everywhere. I would like to find an elementary argument for that, which only uses elementary calculus and topology.

This fact is an immediate corollary of Sard's theorem. Indeed, suppose that every point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is critical. Then the measure of $f(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is zero, so it cannot be open.

Is there a more elementary argument which does not use Sard's theorem? (ideally does not involve measure theory at all).

Comment: You should prove that if the rank is everywhere less than $m$ then the map is not open. If the rank of $f$ equals $k$ on some open set then around each point of that open set there is an open set and coordinates in which $f$ looks like projection onto the first $k$ coordinates. Hence its image is contained in a proper closed subset if $k < m$. This is proved using the inverse function theorem (in Jack Lee's textbook on smooth manifolds it is called the "rank theorem"). Your claim should follow by reducing it to the constant rank case.

Comment: @AsafShachar: the set of points in $\mathbb R^n$ where $\mathrm{rank}(df)\leq k-1$ is a closed set (lower semicontinuity of rank; elementary proof via minors), so $df$ attains its maximum rank on an open set

Comment: @Dap OK, I got it. thanks.

Comment: @DanFox Thanks, I got it. Nice solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Proposition.** *Let $f:M\to N$ be a smooth map between smooth manifolds and suppose that $\mathrm{rk}(df_p)<\dim N$ for all $p\in M$. Then, $f$ is not an open map.*

*Proof.* Let $k=\sup\{\mathrm{rk}(df_p):p\in M\}$. Then, $k<\dim N$. Moreover, 
$$M_k:=\{p\in M:\mathrm{rk}(df_p)=k\}$$
is open in $M$. Thus, the restriction $f:M_k\to N$ is smooth of constant rank $k<\dim N$. By the rank theorem (see, e.g. Lee's book on smooth manifolds), $f$ is locally of the form
$$\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n,\quad(x_1,\ldots,x_k,x_{k+1},\ldots,x_{m})\mapsto(x_1,\ldots,x_k,0,\ldots,0)$$
near $0$. In particular, $f(M_k)$ is not open in $N$. $\square$

Comment: I should clarify that for a general $k$, it is $M_{\ge k}:=\{p\in M:\mathrm{rk}(df_p)\geq k\}$ which is open, but because here $k$ is the maximum we have $M_k=M_{\ge k}$.